# How do I set decimal places when I pull data from Bloomberg using Matlab?

Tags: excel, matlab, bloomberg

I was retrieving data from Bloomberg using Matlab history function and it seems that Matlab set 4 decimal places to be the default. This is sometimes inconsistent with the data that I pulled from Excel. For example:

Here's the Matlab code:

```
[d, sec] = history(c, 'TY1 Comdty', 'PX_LAST', '1982-5-6', '1982-5-6')
```

I get different results from Matlab and Excel:

```
Date    5/6/1982
Excel   72.96875
Matlab  72.9688
```

Is there a way to set the property of history function and get 72.96875 instead of 72.9688?

Answer (score 2):

There is no solution as good as Excel has for displaying number with the desired format.

In Matlab, you can set the `format long` to have 15 decimal places, and `format short` to have 4 decimal places. That's all you have.

Nevertheless, two workarounds. The first uses `round`

```
(1) format long                    %define 15 digit precision
    xround = @(x,d) round(x/d)*d;  %rounding function with d format

    a = xround(72.96875, 0.00001)   %rounding your value by calling 'xround' function
```

It gives

```
    a = 72.968750000000000
```

The second workaround prints a string (not a scalar)

```
(2) sprintf('%.5f', 72.96875)
```

It gives

```
    ans = 72.96875
```

To match Excel with Matlab, you can type

```
[d, sec] = history(c, 'TY1 Comdty', 'PX_LAST', '1982-5-6', '1982-5-6');
d = xround(d, 0.00001);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `format` command to set the display to the desired number of significant digits: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/format.html